# Determining the range of year in a linked list

Tags: java, singly-linked-list

Hello i'm trying to determine the range of years from a linked list and i need help. To achieve this i have 2 variables called minYear and maxYear in my container class that holds the subscriptionYears linked list. The SubscriptionYear reads the year and the cellular data for that year. Class country stores the country name and is the container for the linked list subscriptionYear that stores the year and cellular data for each country.

The minYear is set to 9999. and maxYear is set to 0. Every time i add a subscription to the list i update the minYear and maxYear. And i use the "minYear" and "maxYear" to check if the requested subscription period is valid. How do i implement the minYear and maxYear to check if the requested subscription is valid.

My class Subscriptionyear stores the year and cellular data for that particular year as a double.

```
//stores the year and statistical subscription data for that year
public class SubscriptionYear {

private int year;
private double subscriptions;
SubscriptionYear next;

public SubscriptionYear(int year,double subscriptions)
{
    setYear(year);
    setSubscription(subscriptions);
    this.next = null;
}
public void setYear(int Year)
{
    this.year= Year;
}
public void setSubscription(double value)
{
    this.subscriptions = value;
}
public int getYear()
{
    return year;
}
public double getSubscription()
{
    return subscriptions;
}
public String toString()
{
    return "Number of Subscriptions: "+subscriptions;
}
public void setNode(SubscriptionYear next)
{
    this.next = next;
}
public SubscriptionYear getNext()
{
    return this.next;
}
}
```

class Country: My class Country stores the name of the country and acts a container for linked list of susbcriptionYear that contains the year and stat information for that country. I was able to create the list and successfully print the list but i cannot seem to get the problem solved above. The stats data begins from 1960 to 2012.

```
public class Country  {

private String countryNames;
private SubscriptionYear subscriptions;
private int minYear;
private int maxYear;

public Country(String country)
{
    this.countryNames = country;
    this.subscriptions = null;
    this.maxYear = 0;
    this.minYear = 9999;
    }

//adds the subscription and updates the minYear and maxYear
//Dont think i set up the minYear and maxYear correctly.
public void addSubscriptionYear(int year, double subscription)
{
    SubscriptionYear newNode = new SubscriptionYear(year, subscription);
    if(this.isEmpty())
    {
        newNode.setNode(subscriptions);
        subscriptions = newNode;
        if(newNode.getYear()==1960)
        {
            this.minYear++;
        }
    }
    else{
        SubscriptionYear current = subscriptions;
        while(current.getNext()!=null)
        {
            if(current.getYear()==1960)
            {
                this.minYear++;
            }
           else if(current.getYear()==2012)
           {
              this.maxYear++
           }
         current = current.getNext();
        }
        current.setNode(newNode);   
    }
}

//overrides the toString method and prints out the countries.
public String toString()
{
    String result="";
    result += "\n"+this.countryNames;
    SubscriptionYear current = subscriptions;
    while(current!=null)
    {
        result+="\t"+current.getSubscription();
        current = current.getNext();        
    }
    return result;
}
 //returns countryName
  public String getName()
{
    return this.countryNames;
}
public boolean isEmpty()
{
    return (subscriptions == null);
}
}
```

Comment: Are you trying to find the earliest and latest year among the subscriptions?  Or trying to count how many subscriptions have years of 1960 and 2012?  Also, did you get any compile errors from this?

Comment: I would ask the same questions as @DavidWallace has asked. Also just for the sake of curiosity why aren't you using built in LinkedList class to maintain list of years?

Comment: @RJadhav this was a project by professor we had to follow her guidelines. As she made us write the implementation without using API

Comment: @DavidWallace we are to use the minYears and maxYear variables to use "minYear" and "maxYear" to check if the requested subscription period is valid.

Comment: Does that mean that only subscription year between minyear and maxyear is valid?

Comment: @JenniferFitzgerald Since you know your stats data begin from 1960 to 2012, why can't you just set `minYear` and `maxYear` to 1960 and 2012, respectively? And then perform your year validation for a new node inside your `addSubscriptionYear()` method, by comparing the new `year` with `minYear` and `maxYear`?

Comment: @RJadhav yes between minYear and maxYear. Year of data starts at 1960 and ends at 2012.

Comment: SO I think you should not initialize minYear and maxYear in the constructor. It should only be updated when a new year is added.

Comment: @isim i thought about that but the professor set the minYear at 9999 and maxYear at 0 in the constructor of class country. In the Country constructor:
set "minYear" to a large number (such as 9999);
set "maxYear" to a small number (such as 0).
Whenever a subscription is added to the "subscriptions list", check if you need to update "minYear" and "maxYear".
Later use "minYear" and "maxYear" to check if the requested subscription period is valid.

Comment: @JenniferFitzgerald If you found the answers helpful, please consider upvoting them and marking one as accepted. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Since there is a constraint in your assignment where the `Country` object has to be instantiated with `minYear=9999` and `maxYear=0`, you can update your `Country.addSubscription()` method to perform the comparison and validation.

So something like this should work:

```
public void addSubscriptionYear(int year, double subscription) {
  // check if this new node's year is within the valid range
  if(year > 2012 || year < 1960)
    throw new IllegalArugmentException("New node's year is not within the 1960 and 2012 range"); // or however else you want to handle this

  // check if this new node has a year earlier than this.minYear
  this.minYear = this.minYear > year ?  year : this.minYear;

  // check if this new node has a year late than this.maxYear
  this.maxYear = this.maxYear < year ? year : this.maxYear;

  SubscriptionYear newNode = new SubscriptionYear(year, subscription);
  if(this.isEmpty()) {
    newNode.setNode(subscriptions);
    subscriptions = newNode;
  }
  else{
    SubscriptionYear current = subscriptions;
    while(current.getNext()!=null)          
      current = current.getNext();
    current.setNode(newNode);   
  }
}
```

Each time a new node is to be added, we check whether the new year is less than `this.minYear` or greater than `this.maxYear`. If they are, we adjust `this.minYear` and `this.maxYear` accordingly.

Comment: Seriously?  You're teaching a beginner to use the ternary operator for this?

Comment: @DavidWallace Is that a bad thing? Not exactly sure what the issue is. I would normally refactor codes into smaller, shorter methods. But FWIW, I don't want to confuse OP more.

Comment: Most beginners find the ternary operator confusing.  That's why I used simple `if` statements in my answer.

Comment: @DavidWallace I appreciate your concerns for the beginners. IMHO, it's better for them to learn advance stuff from good, gentle teachers (like yourself), than other less-friendlier ones. For a moment, I thought you're gonna pull the ["clarity over brevity"](https://signalvnoise.com/posts/3250-clarity-over-brevity-in-variable-and-method-names) card :-)

Comment: @DavidWallace I did give a brief explanation towards the end of my answer what those ternary operators are doing.

Answer (score 0):

Somewhere in your `addSubscriptionYear` method, you'll need something like this.

```
if (year < minYear) {
    minYear = year;
}

if (year > maxYear) {
    maxYear = year;
}
```

That way, you're adjusting `minYear` if you discover a subscription with an earlier year than the earliest one you've already found; and  you're adjusting `maxYear` if you discover a subscription with a later year than the latest one you've already found.

You have a few errors in your program too; but I'm sure if you keep working at it, you'll manage to find and remove them.